# Pathfinder, Savage Display

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, critical-hit

I have a question regarding critical hits and the feat [Savage Display](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/savage-display-combat-performance).

If I score a critical hit, do I roll 1d6 for both regular hit damage and the "critical damage"? - so if I get a confirmation its 2d6 total?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Are you asking what the feat does normally, or are you asking how it interacts with critical hits? (The scare quotes make it unclear if you mean real critical damage or the +1d6 from the feat.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precision damage and additional damage dice from weapon special abilities(IE:Flaming) are specifically excluded from being effected by critical hits. Since the additional D6 from Savage display is specifically defined as **NOT** precision damage, and not a weapon special ability, then I would have to say that it would be multiplied.